# How to get the current time in UTC?

Tags: google-search

Searching for "current time UTC" gives a backward answer.

That is, in AEST timezone (UTC+10), it instead responds with the answer that would have been correct if the local timezone had instead been UTC-10. (It seems to get there by interpreting the current local time as if it were the nominal value of the UTC and then converting the result to the local timezone.)

The behavior is different (better) if I ask for the current time in Greenwich, but that doesn't completely solve the problem (because Greenwich is currently on daylight savings time..)

How do I query Google for the UTC as of now?

---

[image: "current time utc": 11:34 am Tuesday, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is 9:34 pm Tuesday, in]

---

[image: "current time greenwich": 2:34 am Tuesday, 16 May 2023 (GMT+1) Time in Greenwich, London, UK]

Answer (score 2):

Searching *current time **in** utc* works:

[image: 10:43 Tuesday, May 16, 2023 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)]

Answer (score 0):

Googling "*current time **gmt***" works correctly.

(It's quite peculiar that googling "current time *utc*" doesn’t.)

Note GMT is different from “Greenwich”, during the northern hemisphere summer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).